# List of line numbers as input for vim

Tags: vim

I have a list of line numbers in a file e.g.

```
1
5
3
```

I want add the same comment to every one of those line numbers within another file:

```
test1 # comment
test2 # comment
test3
test4
test5 # comment
```

Is there a way to treat a file line by line as input for a line number in vim, and perform some operations on it? I know how to target a single line by using

```
5,5s/$/ # comment/
```

but I can't figure out how to get the line numbers from a file into the vim command.

Comment: Your line numbers and where the comments go don't match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use a generated `sed` script:

```
sed 's:$:s/$/ # comment/:' line_nums | sed -f- infile
```

The generated script looks like this:

```
1s/$/ # comment/
5s/$/ # comment/
3s/$/ # comment/
```

And the output from the second `sed` looks like this:

```
test1 # comment
test2
test3 # comment
test4
test5 # comment
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a Vim List from a file:

```
let list = readfile('path/to/list.txt')
```

or if the file has been opened in Vim:

```
let list = getbufline('list.txt', 1, '$')
```

This gets you:

```
:echo list
['1', '5', '3']
```

As a second step, we need to find applicable lines. A `for` loop will do; the line number will be interpolated via `:execute`:

```
for l in list
    execute l . 's/$/ # comment/'
endfor
```

Alternatively, we can misuse the `:global` command for the iteration. This is slower, though, and for `index()` we have to avoid comparing apples (here: line *numbers*) with oranges (here: *Strings* representing line numbers in the list). I still mention this because this is more general; e.g. you could use it to read words or regular expressions from a file to target lines:

```
global/^/if index(list, "" . line('.')) != -1 | s/$/ # comment/ | endif
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for Awk.

```
:%!gawk 'NR == FNR {a[$0] = " \#comment"; next} FNR in a { $0 = $0 a[FNR]} 1' lines.txt -
```

The awk program in expanded out for readability:

```
NR == FNR {
    a[$0] = " #comment";
    next
}

FNR in a {
    $0 = $0 a[FNR]
}

1
```

The basic idea is we send in two files into awk, `lines.txt` & stdin (`-`). The `lines.txt` file we store the line number in an array, `a`, with the comment as the value (`a[$0] = " #comment";`). When going over `stdin` update the line if the line number is inside our array (`FNR in a`). Then print out each line of `stdin` (`1`)

NOTE: I am using `gawk` so your milage may vary. Also must escape, `#` as Vim expands this to the alternative buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Given the extraction of the list already done -- see Ingo's answer.

If you don't have that many lines and indices, the following should be fast enough (it should be faster than the `:global` solution)

```
:call setline(1, map(range(1, max(list)), 'index(list, v:val) >=0 ? printf("test%d # comment", v:val) : v:val'))
```

If the number of lines and of indices grows, a lot, I'm not sure this O(N²) solution will scale. As `:for` loops are slow, I'm not sure how we could proceed efficiently given the tools at our disposal.

May be:

```
:let d = {}
:call map(copy(list), 'extend(d, {v:val: printf("test%d # comment", v:val)})')
:call setline(1, map(range(1, max(list)), 'get(d, v:val, v:val)'))
```

which is definitively convoluted

Yet another convoluted O(N) way is the following

```
:call sort(list)
:call setline(1, map(range(1, slist[-1]), 'v:val == slist[0] ? printf("test%d # comment", remove(slist, 0)) : v:val'))
```